# Prevent USB HDD from spindown

Tags: usb, scripts, hard-drive, cron, spindown

I am fairly new to Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) and I am in need of a little assistance.

I am looking for a way to prevent my USB HDDs from spinning down, because they are fairly old and slow and it really takes them a while to to open and access the files inside which is really annoying. I have a few connected via USB hub to a single USB port on my PC.

I need some sort of script or a crontab that runs periodically accessing those drives so they won't spin down.

I would really appreciate any help on the matter.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This ability is generally built into the firmware. There is a post on Stack Exchange [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5211/345853) which might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the script itself is not quite clear to me. I am a complete newbie in the world of linux and scripting :)